# Combining 3 images with transparency

Tags: php, image-processing

I am working on this project where I want to combine 3 images into one.

What works so far is making each image (a jpg) transparent.
But after merging them into a new png image, the transparency is gone.

Here is the code:

```
function CreateMyCoolOutfitBaby () {

    $Outfitwidth = 250;
    $Outfitheight = 350;

    $newoutfit = imagecreatetruecolor($Outfitwidth, $Outfitheight); // create empty new image

    $dress = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents("http://images180.affili.net/001089/c/bb9c33888aae07d839b6724e31f462bc.jpg"));
    imagealphablending($dress, true);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($dress, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($dress, $white);

    $bag = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents("http://images180.affili.net/000698/6/40afc9ed65a94177635d1c7675fd3756.jpg"));
    imagealphablending($bag, true);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($bag, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($bag, $white);

    $shoe = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents("http://images180.affili.net/000389/4/4482beed9a949f895debe13d9dd28704.jpg"));
    imagealphablending($shoe, true);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($shoe, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($shoe, $white);




    imagealphablending($newoutfit,true); //on each new layer.

    // UN-COMMENT THIS PARAGRAPH TO SEE SINGLE FILES BEING TRANSPARENT
    //header('Content-Type: image/png');
    //imagepng($dress); // output to the browser
    //imagepng($bag); // output to the browser
    //imagepng($shoe); // output to the browser

    // WORKS TILL HERE :)


    // get with and height from images
    $Dresswidth = imagesx($dress);  $Bagwidth = imagesx($bag);  $Shoewidth = imagesx($shoe);    
    $Dressheight = imagesy($dress); $Bagheight = imagesy($bag); $Shoeheight = imagesy($shoe);


    // Calc Dress Position (middle)
    $DressPosWidth  = ( ( $Outfitwidth / 2 )  - ( $Dresswidth / 2 ) );
    $DressPosHeight = ( ( $Outfitheight / 2 ) - ( $Dressheight / 2 ) );
    // Calc Bag Position (right beside dress)
    $BagPosWidth    = ( ( $Outfitwidth / 2 )  - ( $Bagwidth / 2 ) + 60 ); // place bag in middle but more to the right
    $BagPosHeight = ( ( $Outfitheight / 2 ) - ( $Bagheight / 2 ) );
    // Calc Shoe Position (middle under dress)
    $ShoePosWidth   = ( ( $Outfitwidth / 2 )  - ( $Shoewidth / 2 ) );
    $ShoePosHeight = ( ( $Outfitheight / 2 ) - ( $Shoeheight / 2 ) + 100); // place further down

    // merge images together
    imagecopy($newoutfit,$dress,$DressPosWidth,$DressPosHeight,0,0,$Dresswidth,$Dressheight);
    imagealphablending($newoutfit,true);
    imagecopy($newoutfit,$bag,$BagPosWidth,$BagPosHeight,0,0,$Bagwidth,$Bagheight);
    imagealphablending($newoutfit,true);
    imagecopy($newoutfit,$shoe,$ShoePosWidth,$ShoePosHeight,0,0,$Shoewidth,$Shoeheight);
    imagealphablending($newoutfit,true);

    // make sure alpha is saved
    imagesavealpha($newoutfit, true);
    imagealphablending($newoutfit, true);

    // output to browser
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($newoutfit); // output to the browser
    imagedestroy($newoutfit);
}
```

So the single image transparency works fine. Just when $newoutfit is put out, I get a black background and the images are back to a white background...

What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed this using [imagecopymerge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) :

```
<?php

CreateMyCoolOutfitBaby ();

function CreateMyCoolOutfitBaby () {

    $Outfitwidth = 250;
    $Outfitheight = 350;

    $newoutfit = imagecreatetruecolor($Outfitwidth, $Outfitheight); // create empty new image
    imagealphablending($newoutfit, true);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($newoutfit, 0, 0, 0);imagecolortransparent($newoutfit, $black); // Making it transparent

    $dress = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://example.com/dress.jpg'));
    imagealphablending($dress, true);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($dress, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($dress, $white);

    $bag = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://example.com/bag.jpg'));
    imagealphablending($bag, true);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($bag, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($bag, $white);

    $shoe = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://example.com/shoe.jpg'));
    imagealphablending($shoe, true);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($shoe, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($shoe, $white);

    // get with and height from images
    $Dresswidth = imagesx($dress);  $Bagwidth = imagesx($bag);  $Shoewidth = imagesx($shoe);    
    $Dressheight = imagesy($dress); $Bagheight = imagesy($bag); $Shoeheight = imagesy($shoe);


    // Calc Dress Position (middle)
    $DressPosWidth  = ( ( $Outfitwidth / 2 )  - ( $Dresswidth / 2 ) );
    $DressPosHeight = ( ( $Outfitheight / 2 ) - ( $Dressheight / 2 ) );
    // Calc Bag Position (right beside dress)
    $BagPosWidth    = ( ( $Outfitwidth / 2 )  - ( $Bagwidth / 2 ) + 60 ); // place bag in middle but more to the right
    $BagPosHeight = ( ( $Outfitheight / 2 ) - ( $Bagheight / 2 ) );
    // Calc Shoe Position (middle under dress)
    $ShoePosWidth   = ( ( $Outfitwidth / 2 )  - ( $Shoewidth / 2 ) );
    $ShoePosHeight = ( ( $Outfitheight / 2 ) - ( $Shoeheight / 2 ) + 100); // place further down

    // merge images together
    imagecopymerge($newoutfit,$dress,$DressPosWidth,$DressPosHeight,0,0,$Dresswidth,$Dressheight,100);
    imagealphablending($newoutfit,true);

    imagecopymerge($newoutfit,$bag,$BagPosWidth,$BagPosHeight,0,0,$Bagwidth,$Bagheight,100);
    imagealphablending($newoutfit,true);

    imagecopymerge($newoutfit,$shoe,$ShoePosWidth,$ShoePosHeight,0,0,$Shoewidth,$Shoeheight,100);
    imagealphablending($newoutfit,true);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($newoutfit); // output to the browser
    imagedestroy($newoutfit);
}
```

Comment: Works, thanks!But you changed more than imagecopymerge().
You made the background first black, then transparent....
Good job, thanks!

Comment: @DoJoChi i don't see why you want me to delete my answer ?

Comment: This is now going live and is subject to our copyright. Could you please delete the code above?

Comment: @DoJoChi: Code submitted on [so] and on [se] in general is not subject to your copyright. You have no right requesting it to be deleted. See the copyright at the footer of this page. Actually, you must give attribution to HamZa and to Stack Overflow if you are planning to use this code in your product.

Comment: @DoJoChi This is being discussed on [Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254493), you're invited to participate if you want to.

Comment: @DoJoChi if it's subject to your copyright (which it is not), how are you going to pay HamZa now that he has helped your product?

Comment: @DoJoChi - I can't speak for HamZa, but he would probably remove any references to your company's name so the answer remains generic. It happens on occasion with the SSL questions. We get the domain name, find the problem, and then change it to `example.com` upon request. Keep in mind the history is always available, so you can only be accommodated to a certain degree.