# Put a PNG over a PNG and preserve transparency with PHP

Tags: php, image, png

Lets say I have a PNG image as a background named background.png. Then I want to add another PNG image (other.png) over background.png, however I want to maintain other.png's transparency. However, other.png needs to be at a specific x and y coordinate over background.png. Is this possible with PHP?

Comment: Please share what you have tried. whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: [Maybe this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14101169/1401975) ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985583/transparent-png-over-jpg-in-php